# Speech recognition in iOS periodically fails - beep does not sound after hitting microphone button

Tags: ios, voice-dictation

This problem has occurred on my iPhone 5 with all versions of iOS that have been available for it.

When you want to do voice dictation you hit the microphone key on the keyboard, the microphone iPhone appears and you hear a beep, And you start talking in the icon flashes as it hears the sounds.  When finished you hit the Done button and your transcribed speech is returned.  This is the behavior when things work properly.

Frequently when I hit the microphone button, The microphone icon appears But there is no beep to let me know it has started listening. However the icon does flash in response to sound. When I'm done speaking and I hit the done button, no text is returned. The next time I hit the button it will work - every time.

Under continuous multiple use of hitting the microphone button the problem does not happen. It only happens after some period of nonuse of the feature. But as I said the second attempt after the failure always works.

Is anyone seeing this?

Comment: Interesting. My first thought was the silent switch, or volume set to 0, but since it works the second time, that obviously isn't the case. What about Siri? Does that beep the first time like it is supposed to?

Comment: Good thought about Siri - it works every time.

Comment: Have you performed a HARD Reboot (hold Home + Lock)?

Comment: Apparently basically no one else is seeing this problem. You could restore the phone, to see if that helps at all. Also, you could consider taking it to an Apple store (schedule an appointment) to see if they have any fixes.

Comment: I second Matt and bassplayers answer. I'd try hard reboot, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happens to me periodically. It's so annoying when I can speak into the microphone and see the line wiggle around as if it is hearing what I'm saying but then when I finish it doesn't actually type any text for me. However, I just read online that sometimes you can fix it if you force close background apps (to free up memory) and also temporarily toggle into and out of Airplane Mode (to reset network connectivity). I haven't tried that myself yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach did not seem to help me recently.  So I'm still stuck with the original problem and would appreciate any advice.